# treeview and mvvm I don't populate the tree view

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview

I have the following code.

My TreeViewItem:

```cs
class ComponenteNodoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    private List<ComponenteNodoViewModel> _children;
    private bool _isExpanded;
    private bool _isSelected;


    public ComponenteNodoViewModel Parent { get; set; }


    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            _isExpanded = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsExpanded");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsSelected");
        }
    }


    public List<ComponenteNodoViewModel> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set { _children = value; }
    }

}
```

My ViewModel of the view in which I have the treeView. I have more elements in the GUI, also some bottoms and so on, but I only put the code that has relationship with the treeView.

```cs
public List<ComponenteNodoViewModel> ComponenteJerarquia { get; private set; }

...

private void componenteJerarquiaConstruirArbol(List<vComponentesEstructuras> paramNodos)
{

    List<ComponenteNodoViewModel> misNodos = new List<ComponenteNodoViewModel>();

    ComponenteNodoViewModel miNodo = new ComponenteNodoViewModel();
    miNodo.Nombre = "Prueba";
    misNodos.Add(miNodo);
    ComponenteJerarquia = new List<ComponenteNodoViewModel>(misNodos);
}
```

And finally my xaml of the view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GTS.CMMS.Client.Views.ucMaquinasPrincipalView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1000">


    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="232" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="757" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="309*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="350*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ComponenteJerarquia}" Margin="6,6,8,5" Name="trvComponente" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ComponenteNodoViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ComponenteNodoViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>         
            </TreeView>                    
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that when I call the componenteJerarquiaConstruirArbol method, the treeview is not populated.

I think that the problem is the binding, but I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The propperty `ComponenteJerarquia` is just a plain property, so when you set it, the binding system isn't notified that it needs to update the binding. You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in that class and raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter.

OK, the other part of this is that you shouldn't be putting your HierarchicalDataTemplates inside your TreeView - that's making it think you're trying to put those in the actual tree. Move those templates up to your Resources instead.

Comment: I implement the INotifyPropertyChanged, but now I get other error, that says: the collection must be empty before the use of ItemSource.

Comment: You implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for the ViewModel for GTS.CMMS.Client.Views.ucMaquinasPrincipalView? I see you have it for ComponenteNodoViewModel, but you didn't post the entire other class. Also, List<> doesn't implement ICollectionChanged, which will be required if you want to make changes and have it update automatically. Perhaps use ObservableCollection<>.